# PAX-URL: "Protocol not supported" at Felix's startup

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, pax

I'm using PAX-URL to launch a Felix based project from Eclipse. I use the assembly protocol to avoid having to pre-pack my bundles.

In the project, felix is started using the felix.jar and a config.properties which includes felix.auto.start.1=assembly:foo/bar/classes to start one of my unpacked bundles.

The trouble is, felix doesn't know about the pax-url protocols until *after* it's finished reading that config file, so I get an "Unknown Protocol: assembly" error.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to tell Felix to load pax-url at boot time already?

Thanks!

---

The same problem is solved by  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103505/cannot-use-pax-urls-assembly-protocol-with-auto-started-bundles-in-felix-config). The way it's asked gives you a different way to look for the solution, so I'm going to not mark this question as a duplicate. Thanks Bjorn for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cheat, adding pax url to the bootclasspath (depends on how you actually launch felix) and add the following system property to the starting vm:
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.ops4j.pax.url

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I ultimately got it to work following the advice and link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103505/cannot-use-pax-urls-assembly-protocol-with-auto-started-bundles-in-felix-config). I was able to do it without any bootclasspath changes

Comment: @Miquel: If you find a good solution yourself, please post it as an answer and accept it. This helps others find it faster (users often don't read the comments, they just skim the accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks @Björn Pollex, I've added the answer explicitly